# Accessing globals from URL-to-php function call

Tags: php, scope, global

Is it possible to access globals inside a function that was called via a URL - like this:

**URL**

`example.com/download.php?fn=download&fname=file`

Does the first example below not work because the function call goes straight to the `download()` function without reading the rest of the php script? (i.e. where `$var1, $var2` are declared).

**download.php**

```
<?php

$var1 = 'foo';
$var2 = 'bar';

global $current_user;  // from elsewhere

if ($_GET['fn'] == "download")
    if (!empty($_GET['fname']))
        download($_GET['fname'], $current_user);

function download($fname, $current_user)
{
    // Access the global variables in this scope
    global $var1; 
    global $var2;

    $output = $fname . $var1 . $var2;

    echo $output  // no output here...
}
```

But this works with the same URL as above:

```
<?php

global $current_user;  // from elsewhere

if ($_GET['fn'] == "download")
    if (!empty($_GET['fname']))
        download($_GET['fname'], $current_user);

function download($fname, $current_user)
{
    // Access the global variables in this scope
    $var1 = 'foo'; 
    $var2 = 'bar';

    $output = $fname . $var1 . $var2;

    echo $output  // "filefoobar"
}
```

Is there a way of doing this, or do I just have to declare my variables in the function and skip using `global`? (I know `global` is often ill-advised etc...)

Comment: I can't see why that shouldn't work. Is that the exact code you are using?

Comment: From your latest edit something's not right - you claim that the `$fname` variable isn't being printed now. Seems most likely that your download function isn't being called at all.

Comment: The only explanation would be that `$var1` is not actually `global`. It depends on how your script is actually executed. See the duplicate. If that doesn't help, add more information to un-duplify it.